# Show function series is uniformly convergent by the derivative and pointwise convergent

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

This is my thinking: I tried to use apagoge to show that if the series is not uniformly convergent to sum function then by the definition and the derivative of each function in series will lead to contraction. However, I tried several times and found this method maybe is not feasible. I wonder which is the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Find $m$ with $\frac1m<\frac\epsilon4$.
By pointwise convergence, there exists $N$ such that $|f_n(\frac rm)-f(\frac rm)|<\frac\epsilon4$ holds for all $n\ge N$, for the finitely many $r=1,2,\ldots,m-1$.
Every $x\in(0,1)$ is at most $\frac1m$ apart from one of the $\frac rm$. For $n,k\ge N$ we conclude
$$\begin{align}|f_n(x)-f_k(x)|&\le |f_n(x)-f_n(\tfrac rk)|+|f_n(\tfrac rk)-f(\tfrac rk)|+|f(\tfrac rk)-f_k(\tfrac rk)|+|f_k(x)-f_k(\tfrac rk)|\\
&=|(x-\tfrac rk)f_n'(\xi)|+|f_n(\tfrac rk)-f(\tfrac rk)|+|f(\tfrac rk)-f_k(\tfrac rk)|+|(x-\tfrac rk)f_k'(\eta)|\\
&<\frac1m+\frac\epsilon4+\frac\epsilon 4+\frac 1m\\
&<\epsilon\end{align} $$
and from this $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: (+1) Very nice.